# Mysqli multi query not working, despite appearing correctly formed

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on a Php function that interacts with my database to add specializations for a particular user. I figured using mysqli multi query was the best way to go about accomplishing this. Unfortunately none of the code for the queries is executing correctly. The db connection is working without a hitch, and the individual queries when typed into my databases web app work.

```
function assign_specialties($id, $specialties) {
    $conn = new mysqli($GLOBALS['servername'], $GLOBALS['username'], $GLOBALS['password'], 'visio');
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("$conn->connect_errno: $conn->connect_error");
    }
    $query = "";
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $id);
    foreach ($specialties as $specialty) {
        $specialty = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $specialty);
        $query .= " INSERT INTO member_specialization (member_id, specialization_name) VALUES ('$id', '$specialty');";
    }
    //$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query);
    if ($conn->multi_query($query)) {
        echo "<script> alert('yes')</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<script> alert('$query')</script>";
    }

    $conn->close();
}
```

I also have each **query** seperated by a semicolon. This is the first time i've tried multi query so I know it has to be user error, I just can't figure out what that error is.

Comment: Try a leading space character `" INSERT ...;"`

Comment: Doesn't appear to be changing anything with the result

Comment: Try echoing out your sql queries to check for mistakes. If you can't see any in the echo, try running the echoed queries by copy pasting them directly into db (phpmyadmin) just to rule out sql error.

Comment: I already did this actually. With the statement             echo "<script> alert('$query')</script>"; I also put the individual statements in the webapp and it inserts them succesfully

Comment: Why are you escaping the full query instead of parameters?

Comment: I'll go ahead and correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

> Data inside the query should be properly escaped.

You are using mysqli_real_escape_string() on the entire query, the only string that needs to be escaped is your variable $specialty.

Additionally you're using both procedural style and object oriented style in your function. Whichever style you prefer it is good practice to be consistent.

```
$query = "";
foreach ($specialties as $specialty) {
    $specialty = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $specialty);
    $query .= "INSERT INTO member_specialization
              (member_id, specialization_name) 
              VALUES
              ('$id', '$specialty');";
}

mysqli_multi_query($conn, $query);
```

Comment: This was precisely the answer. xycf7's comment was also correct.